# What is the bootstrap panel equivalent in angular material?

Tags: html, angular-material2

If you go to the [official Angular Material website](https://material.angular.io/components/card/overview), you'll see the examples are wrapped in what looks to be Bootstrap panels (see Basic Card).  Yet there is no material component for these panels.  The closest I can find is mat-card, which does not appear the same.

Is there a native html element for this?  What am I missing?

Comment: I need this type of panels too and I can't find an equivalent, what did you used instead?

Comment: mat-card.  It's weird.

Comment: You're not missing anything. The component you are talking about is just divs and styles ([source](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/a3ffdb28a4760e6e3b3bbf691bbd9ac11b6df508/src/app/shared/example-viewer/example-viewer.html))